# Where does Macports install freerdp

Tags: remote-desktop, macports

I just installed freerdp with macports but I can't seem to find the binary anywhere. xfreerdp command doesn't run either.

This is the command I ran: sudo port clean freerdp && sudo port install freerdp

```
--->  Cleaning FreeRDP
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/bin/sudo) is setuid or setgid
Warning: port definitions are more than two weeks old, consider updating them by running 'port selfupdate'.
--->  Computing dependencies for FreeRDP
--->  Fetching archive for FreeRDP
Warning: Your DNS servers incorrectly claim to know the address of nonexistent hosts. This may cause checksum mismatches for some ports.
--->  Attempting to fetch FreeRDP-1.1.0-beta+2013071101_0.darwin_12.x86_64.tbz2 from *link*
--->  Attempting to fetch FreeRDP-1.1.0-beta+2013071101_0.darwin_12.x86_64.tbz2 from *link*
--->  Attempting to fetch FreeRDP-1.1.0-beta+2013071101_0.darwin_12.x86_64.tbz2 from *link*
--->  Fetching distfiles for FreeRDP
--->  Verifying checksums for FreeRDP
--->  Extracting FreeRDP
--->  Configuring FreeRDP
--->  Building FreeRDP
--->  Staging FreeRDP into destroot
--->  Installing FreeRDP @1.1.0-beta+2013071101_0
--->  Activating FreeRDP @1.1.0-beta+2013071101_0
--->  Cleaning FreeRDP
--->  Updating database of binaries: 100.0%
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  No broken files found.
```

No idea where it installs the binaries though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed FreeRDP on my Mac AIR using Mac Ports too and had the same issue. I opened a Terminal and performed this command to locate the binary:

```
cd /
find . -iname \*freerdp\*
```

This gave me a lot of output, but I was able to locate the binary in this location:

```
/opt/local/bin/xfreerdp
```

I found that the /opt/local/bin folder is in my local path environment variable. This means that all you should have to type is "xfreerdp" (without the quotes) to launch the program from the command line.

I was able to connect to my Windows server with this command:

```
xfreerdp /u:<username> /p:<password> /v:<IP address of my windows server>
```

So far, FreeRDP works well, the response time is nice.

Hope this helps!